# Implement function to QT Button

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I cant find any solution for the problem. I created an ui with qt and wanted to implement a function for the button. It works if i delete the buttons in the header file.

Error

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/QT3.dir/QT3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o: in function `MainWindow::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)': mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to` MainWindow::on_nextStep_clicked()'
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/QT3.dir/QT3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o: in function `MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)': mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to` MainWindow::on_nextStep_clicked()'

Header File

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW3_H_
#define MAINWINDOW3_H_

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

//QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
//namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
//QT_END_NAMESPACE

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    signals:

private slots:

//    void on_pushButton_5_clicked(); // add Wall
//    void on_pushButton_clicked(); // oben
//    void on_pushButton_2_clicked(); // links
//    void on_pushButton_3_clicked(); // rechts
//    void on_pushButton_4_clicked(); // unten

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_nextStep_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
protected:
//    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);
};

#endif /* MAINWINDOW3_H_ */
```

Cpp File

```
#include "mainwindow3.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QObject>

#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

//    ui->graphicsView->installEventFilter(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    std::cout << "add btn clicked()" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? The Qt3 part seems confusing.

Comment: its version 5.12.8. sry for the confusion, but its my third qt test project and my other projects works fine.

Comment: Your code shows you did not implement `on_nextStep_clicked()` in your .cpp file.

Comment: I know if i implement on_nextStep_clicked() it works, but it didnt work my with PushButtons and i named them correctly.

Comment: Then you need to delete `void on_nextStep_clicked();` from your header, having that in your header in a slot requires the function to be defined in the .cpp file.

Comment: I did comment the line and also the line with the function in the cpp file

Comment: Do a build clean.

Comment: @Stefan1996t Please use the [eclipse] tag only for general questions about the Eclipse (Java) IDE. For Eclipse as C/C++ IDE specific questions, use the tag [eclipse-cdt]. The choice of tags affects who (with what knowledge) reads your question.

Answer (score 1):

a slot is just another method in Qt for asyn events

if you define in the header:

```
void on_nextStep_clicked();
```

then you need a implementation in the cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_nextStep_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Hallo Welt!";
    qDebug() << "on_nextStep_clicked()";
}
```